# HTTPS POST data is not encrypted

Tags: php, ssl

I am trying to understand in practice, what are the differences between POSTING data using the same web page with and without SSL (HTTPS) so I've created a PHP file with a single form, a textfield and a button to post data and I didn't notice any changes on the headers except one CACHE variable.

For instance, after posting the form, under the Network tab of the Developer Tools, I can fully read the header and form contents in both connections with or without SSL.

My question is: With a https:// localhost POST, aren't this headers suposed to appear encripted?

Comment: Isn't it logical that you can see what your browser has just sent over the wire? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL is an end-to-end encryption between the web server and the web browser; this means that the traffic in between those two endpoints is encrypted.

Since you're at one end (the browser), you can see what has been sent and received, but someone in between can't.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! Will you please advise me of a method from which I could I cross check this encryption? I am on Windows.

Comment: You could set up a local proxy that intercepts the traffic your browser sends to the remote server and verify that it's indeed encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

The entire request and the response will be encrypted between the browser and the server.

Since you are looking at the headers using the browser, you won't see the encrypted form of the data as it has access to the unencrypted version.